# Python access to NFS quota information?

Tags: python, nfs, quota

Are there any Python modules that will let me get access to `NFS` quota information without having to parse the output of the `quota` command?  I am aware that if I were sufficiently motivated I could write my own ONC/RPC code using Python's `xdrlib` module, but I am hoping with all my heart that I do not have to get that intimately involved with the innards of NFS.

Ideally, I am hoping for an existing RPC implementation, or some higher-level module (like a wrapper for an existing C library or something).

An acceptable substitute would be something like the `quota` command that produces more machine-readable output.

Comment: Hmm.  I see that more recent versions of the quota-utils package include options for better output (e.g., `--raw-grace` and `--no-wrap`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was spawned originally by problems with version 3.13 of the `quota` command, which is essentially useless as a tool for the end user to determine quota information.  For example, if `alice` runs `quota`, she might see output like this:

```
Disk quotas for user alice (uid 100): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
fileserver.example.com:/staff/b/bob
                9254720  9728000 10240000          119768       0       0
```

Alice would rightly wonder what this had to do with her account.

It turns out that the minds behind the `quota-utils` package at long last realized the problems inherent in the tool; with version 4.00 (available in Fedora 16) there are several new options available that turn the `quota` command into something that actually produces useful information.

Of particular interest is the `-f` option:

```
-f, --filesystem-list     display quota information only for given filesystems
```

So now, a user can run:

```
quota -f ~
```

And get the quota information for their home directory.  Additionally, the `-s` option will display "human readable" numbers instead of displaying everything as blocks.

For Alice, this might look like:

```
$ quota -s -f ~
Disk quotas for user alice (uid 100): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
fileserver.example.com:/staff/a/alice
              9038M   9500M  10000M            120k       0       0
```

Additionally, there are two options that make it much easier to process the output from `quota` in a script:

- The `-w` option inhibits the line wrapping when the "filesystem" name is too long.
- The `-p` option displays `0` for the grace time if the user is not in an over-quota situation.  This means that there are always the same number of fields (whereas with the previous version of `quota` the number of fields could vary depending on the situation).

Combining all of the above, we get something like this:

```
$ quota -wp -f ~
Disk quotas for user alice (uid 100): 
     Filesystem   space   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
fileserver.example.com:/staff/a/alice 9254720  9728000 10240000       0  119768 0
```

Which is *much* more useful for automation.

Comment: v4.01 complains that ~ is not a mountpoint. For me, `quota -wp -f $(dirname ~)` works but in general the mountpoint could be higher up.

Answer (score 0):

```
command_array = ['quota', '-wp', '-f', '/home/nfs/user1']
output = subprocess.check_output(command_array)
# use only the third line, this is util info
beauty_output = output.split('\n')[2].split()
remote_fs = beauty_output[0]
blocks = beauty_output[1]
quota = beauty_output[2]
limit = beauty_output[3]
...
```

Consider that /home/nfs/user1 is the nfs mount point.
I have done this way.